# Calculate used space in Oracle query?

Tags: java, oracle

I want to calculate DB size named "KIN" schema of oracle database.
Can anybody suggest the query?

I have used this query

```
SELECT sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 gb_used 
FROM dba_segments 
WHERE owner NOT IN ('SYS', 'SYSTEM');
```

I'm getting this error

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
```

Comment: what user are you running this as?

Comment: Normal user with a username and password...@davegreen100

Comment: the dba_segments view is owned by the SYS user, i would guess your user doesn't have permissions to read this view

Comment: Is there any way to calculate the size of the database we are accessing with username and password???

Comment: change the query to read from user_segments, this should then show you the size of the objects owned by the "normal" user. technically this is not the size of the database, as that also includes the SYS, SYSTEM users, so it will show you the size of the "normal" users schema

Comment: When I tried with user_segments Its returning (null)

Comment: try selecting from user_objects, if there is nothing in there then the "normal" user you are connected as owns nothing in your database, in which case you need to find out which owner does own the objects, and then either connect as that user or connect as SYSTEM or SYS (undesirable) and select from dba_objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

This error means you are connected to the database through a user which lacks select privilege on the DBA_SEGMENTS views. It is normal, indeed good practice, to restrict access on the DBA views to only certain users.

> "When I tried with user_segments Its returning (null)"

So that sounds like your user doesn't own any tables or indexes. Again not surprising: many systems segregate access accounts from schema owning accounts.

Probably the query you want would be on `all_segments` - except that there is no ALL_ equivalent for DBA_SEGMENTS. So you'll need to ask your DBA to run the query for you.